# Getting error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when using Python open()

Tags: python, path, load, file-not-found, listdir

I have seen many similar questions to mine, but still I can't resolve the issue. I'd be grateful if someone could help. 
I have a folder with 3 .txt files (Text1.txt, Text2.txt, & Text3.txt) in it, plus some other files. I want to read these three files and pass them through a function. I wrote a for loop as follows:

```
file_list = [f for f in listdir("Path_to_my_files") if 
isfile(join("Path_to_my_files",f))]

def Read (files):
    for f in files:
      if f.endswith (".txt"):
        data = open(r'Path_to_my_files/f')
        text = data.read()
```

The error message I get is:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Text1.txt'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data = open(r'Path_to_my_files/' + f )` ?

Comment: also : `with open(filename) as f:` context is suggested to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html), i.e.:

```
from glob import glob

p = "/path/to/*.txt"
for t in glob(p):
    with open(t) as f:
        text = f.read()
    # do something with text
```